# Get combinations with repetition where combinations are > a given number

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am trying to find a way to:

a) Get a number of all the combinations with repetition in an array

b) Get which of these combinations has a sum greater than a given number

Please forgive my terms here, I'm not good at math so a lot of this is just how I think about things.

i.e

```
E = [1,2,3]
r = 5 // Size of the combination
n = 5 // The number of "picks"
x = 10 // The minimum value of the sum of the combination to make it "valid"
```

Combinations here are:

```
[1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,2]
...
[1,2,3,3,3] // Because this is > X, this should be counted as a "valid" result
```

I basically want to get the ratio of "valid" combinations in a series of combinations.

Does this make sense?

Comment: So is the point getting the actual combinations (a programming task) or counting how many there are (mathematical task)?

Comment: By the way, what is $E$? You said that "E=[1,2,3]", but how is it related to the other things?

Comment: E is the array of values that can be used. I realize now my example is wrong. I will edit it. So, for example, there could be multiple instances of a value in there, i.e [1,1,2,3]. If this was the case, then in the list of combinations, you could have both [1,1,1,1,1] and [1,1,1,1,1] again, because they are 2 different 1s. Does this make sense?

Comment: As for if this is a mathematical task or programming, the answer is "either". Whichever one gets me my result is what Im looking for. I am trying to calculate the probability of a person getting a specific result given an array of values over n picks from that array.

Comment: To clarify. I dont actually need every combination printed out. I just need the ratio of valid combinations / total combinations

Comment: So basically you have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5$, and if these nonnegative coefficients are chosen randomly, then the question is: What is the probability that $x_1 + 2x_2 +3x_3 > 10$

Comment: Yes, kinda. Why do you say x1+x2+x3=5 though? Or is that just an arbitrary value you have chosen?

Comment: It's because there are five things that you can choose. $x_1$ is how many times you choose the first element, $x_2$ is how many times you choose the second element, $x_3$ is how many times you choose the third element.

Comment: So I think I can get the total number of combinations. That is (n+r-1)!/r!(n-1)!, I think, but now I need to get the valid ones, and thats where Im stumped.